# How do I edit a function in PSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, psql

I created a default function in PGADMIN but the server doesn't have that software.

How can I edit the function using PSQL?

The closest I've seen is

```
\df+ function_name
```

but the output is garbled and not editable.

---

This will open the function using a default editor.

```
\ef function_name()
```

But then when I save it, it saves as this...

**"/tmp/psql.edit.20631.sql"** in the bin folder,

which doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Type ; after finish editing
db=> \ef get_item
db-> ;
CREATE FUNCTION

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After you edit the function with `\ef`, you need to enter `\g` or `;` to execute the statement that updates the function.

So it would be

```
\ef function_name()
[edit away]
\g
```

Comment: Had to use `\ef function_name` on 9.3